# Trigger onserverclick without physically clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to abstract the file-browse dialog from the user and only show one button for upload, like so:

```
<input type="button" id="uploadFile" value="Upload" /> 
<div class="hidden">
    <form id="uploadFileForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="browseForFiles" />
        <input type="button" id="submitFile" value="Submit File" runat="server" 
               onclick="return true;"
               onserverclick="SubmitFile_Click" />
    </form>
</div>
```

```
$("#uploadFile").click(function () {
    // trigger hidden file dialog
    $("#browseForFiles").click(); // works
});

$("#browseForFiles").change(function () {
    $("#submitFile").click(); // doesn't work; doesn't call onserverclick
});
```

Physically clicking on the `submitFile` button works fine and calls the server-side method, but since I want the actual server-side button to be hidden, the user can't physically click it. **How do you fake a physical click in jQuery/Javascript?**

**EDIT :**
I also tried:

```
<input type="submit" id="submitFile" value="Submit File" runat="server" 
       onclick="return true;"
       onserverclick="SubmitFile_Click" />
```

```
$("#uploadFileForm").submit(); // doesn't work either
```

Comment: Maybe try: `$('#submitFile')[0].click();`  Be aware, i'm not an ASP guy

Comment: @A.Wolff: Thanks! Your suggestion worked too after I fixed my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("input[id$='submitFile']").click();` works.

I didn't realize that ASP.NET was replacing the ID of the element to something like `ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_submitFile` even if regular HTML controls were used!

`$("input[id$='submitFile']")[0].click();` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$('#uploadFileForm').submit()
```